# How to remove grid children in a specific RowDefinition?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm drawing the controls dynamically at run time inside a grid. I want to clear all children under a specific control when the user taps on it. I have this but this only remove the RowDefinitions:

```
   var currentRow = Grid.GetRow((BindableObject)sender);
   for (int i = currentRow + 1; i < grdDynamic.RowDefinitions.Count; i++)
   {
       grdDynamic.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(i);
   }
```

but I need to clear all the grid children in those RowDefinitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove the children in your grid with the tapped row as attribute.

```
    var children = grdDynamic.Children.ToList();
    foreach (var child in children.Where(child => Grid.GetRow(child) == row)) {
        grdDynamic.Children.Remove(child);
    }
```

It loops over all children in your grid and removes the child if its row equals the tapped row.